# Database design and SQL query for the activity feed?

Tags: sql, database-design

I want to build some activity feed similar to facebook. Before I ask my question, I want to explain my mySQL database design. I have a users table, ie.

```
user_id     name     other columns
userA       -           -
userB       -           -
userC       -           -
userD       -           -
```

The users can follow each other, and here is the table called 'followers'

```
id      user_id         follower_id
1        userA            userB
2        userD            userB
3        userB            userA
-
-
-
```

As we see, in above table, userB is following userA and userD.

Now my question is, when ANY of the user in the user_id to whom userB is following, does an activity, should be notified. Should i make another table, lets say, 'activity', something like:

```
user_id     activity_type   activity_link  activity_date  
userA           note
userB           photo
userC           note
userD           photo
```

**Question 1: Do I need to make additional table (shown above) to store the activities or it can be done without that?**

**Question 2: As userB in following only userA and userD, therefore userB is concerned only with the users he is following, how can i build the sql query for that? sth like:**

```
 Select * from activity where user_id exists in user_id in followers table where follower_id = userB
```

(This is my idea, can you help me building SQL query)

Thanks for reading this long question and possible help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will need a table to store activity data. Otherwise, you would have to store this data elsewhere.

The easiest way to write the query is to use a join. In this case, we only want activity rows if the current user is following, so we can use an inner join.

```
select * from activity a
    join followers f on a.user_id = f.user_id
where follower_id = 'userB'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your present design seems reasonable as to what has been included. But otherwise it seems to be particularly lacking a way to notify users about *new* activity information.

So far I imagine it implemented as a sort of a queue table, let's call it `new_activity`. A probable design could be like this:

```
follower_id int
activity_id int
```

Probably the two should be a combined PK.

Notifications are triggered by inserts into `activity`. *'Triggered... triggered... aha, then it should probably be a trigger on `activity` for insert!'*. But of course. When a new activity information appears, you should link the newly active users with the followers to form a proper `follower/activity` pair list, which is accordingly inserted into `new_activity`.

Also, I think, there could also be a trigger on `followers` for insert. When a new `user/follower` pair appears, you might want to run through `activity` for that user for some very recent period, like a week or a day, you choose, to be able to notify the new follower that there has been some (or hasn't been any) activity just recently.

The notifications should be removed as soon as the user has been notified, i.e., I understand, as soon as the information about new activity has been requested. Now that seems a bit trickier then inserts. I think there should be a stored procedure like `GetNewActivity (@follower_id int)` that reads all rows from `new_activity` for the specified follower, returns them as a table and also removes them from `new_activity` so user wasn't notified about those again. And I do not see so far why all the operations could not be grouped inside a transaction. If you manage to design your system in such a way that new activity info can only be acquired via `GetNewActivity` kind of a way, then I think there should be no problems about repeated or missed new activity notifications.

I am not going to rob you of the pleasure of designing both the conceptual and the actual queries so far. However if that proves a bit of a challenge to you, I'm ready to help as well as, I'm sure, all the community are. And I'm inviting the latter to all the criticism about the design presented that they inevitably possess. :)

As to your Question #2 and also why I am so far restraining from giving you query examples... Well, you have already been [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905767/database-design-and-sql-query-for-the-activity-feed/4905799#4905799) with one way how to get activities from users that are followed by a particular user (follower). I'm almost sure you will be given alternative solutions and I, for one, was about to do particularly that, but then I thought better of it.

It seems like you are somewhat new to joins or at least not very confident about how to use them, and I would like to encourage you to study the simple query `ar` has provided you with, because it is a pattern you are going to need to build the queries for new activity notification part of your problem. That is, I would advise you to try to do that part first by yourself, and that is why I'm not distracting you with a different solution to your second question but rather pointing you to the mentioned query: it is both a good solution and a useful starting point for building other queries you will need.

Comment: I like you solution, it allows me to fetch recent activity very efficiently. But when the user has 100 follower, I have to do 100 inserts to log his activity, this seems very inefficient.

Comment: @Ivan Virabyan: Thanks for the feedback. I'd expect the `new_activity` table to be one of the hottest spots in the entire schema. Consequently, it should probably be put in a separate database, which would be placed on some high-speed storage device (at least, at the stage when the service becomes so immensely popular that people end up having multitudes of followers). As an alternative, the `followers` table could have a `last_followed` timestamp column. The new activity would then have to be derived based on that timestamp and `activity.activity_date`.